# Google drive resumable upload and CORS

Tags: google-drive-api, cors

I'm using the google drive resumable upload API and am seeing a lack of CORS headers in some cases. The pre-flight to OPTIONS always returns 200 but when making the actual requests, the headers are missing in some cases, which means I am not able to read the responses.

Not seeing CORS headers when:
 - uploading the final chunk
 - creating a resumable session
 - querying for session status

Seeing CORS headers when:
 - uploading a non-final chunk (308 status response)

Answer (score 0):

CORS is not currently completely supported for resumable uploads. Sorry. Google are working to fix this.

Edit: Now fixed. See http://github.com/googledrive/cors-upload-sample